# Running Tomcat With A Specified Root And Home Page

Tags: tomcat

I can start up tomcat using the start.sh file included with it, but are there any arguments I can use to do the following:

- Start Tomcat Serving At A Specified Root Directory
- Force Tomcat To Pull Up A Specified Home Page In A Browser

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To serve pages at the root of your Tomcat installation, you need to modify your server.xml file, located under the following path {CATALINA_HOME}/conf/server.xml

It should look something like this.

```
<Context path=""/>
```

As for your second question, please refer to the documentation - http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_override_the_default_home_page_loaded_by_Tomcat.3F

Comment: As per the documentation, you should not be configuring contexts in server.xml.